# Is Hubbles law due to Gravity?

Tags: cosmology, gravity, velocity, distance, cosmological-constant

Hubble's law states that Distance is  proportional to Velocity. A [ScienceDirect](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/hubbles-law) article states that Classical Hubble expansion is characterized by a proportional increase in the rate of expansion groups based on the distance from the main center of gravity

So  is it due to gravity?

Comment: The first two sections [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann_equations) respectively provide the assumptions on which Hubble's law holds viz. $H=\dot{a}/a$ and the derivation, rooted in general relativity and hence gravity construed in terms of spacetime curvature, of differential equations constraining the scale factor $a$.

Comment: "center of gravity" is misleading. As long as the Cosmological Principle holds there is no center of gravity. Its just that in cosmological distances galaxies are receding from each other, whereby their peculiar velocities are negligible. Science is fun, keep it up!

Comment: good question! this I thought of as well;

Comment: Thanks a lot!, @WilliamMartens

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Hubble's law is due to the expansion of the universe.

I can't say what the ScienceDirect article meant because you didn't link it, but the description of what it wrote does not sound sensible either.

**Edit**: from the link, the relevant quote is:

> A special place in astrophysics is the effect of Hubble—expanding groups of galaxies, accompanied by a proportional increase in the rate of expansion groups based on the distance from the main center of gravity.

What this means is that if you have a group of galaxies,* then when space expands, the galaxies appear to recede from one another at a speed given by the Hubble Law. The Hubble Law itself is still caused by expansion of space.

*Note "groups of galaxies" (i.e. galaxy clusters) are gravitationally bound - that is, they do not expand because their gravitational attraction is strong enough to overrule cosmic expansion.

Comment: Sorry, Link: https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/physics-and-astronomy/hubbles-law

Comment: Just a detail. Galaxies belonging to a cluster are gravitationally bound. So they don't feel the expansion, instead they have peculiar velocities. Only supercluster consisting of many smaller galaxy cluster participate in the expansion.

Answer (score 3):

Hubble's law *describes* the expansion of the universe. Is it due to gravity? Well gravity is the interaction by which space time responds to energy soruces (and therefore does anything at all), so yes. But you can't just say that any hypothetical universe containing gravity will therefore automatically obey Hubble's law.

This depends on the constituents of the universe and also which "part of spacetime" you're interested in. There are some details about the present epoch (such as matter dominating over radiation) which have been shown to inevitably follow from more basic properties of the early universe. But there are also plenty where we are far from having a theoretical explanation. One of these is dark energy which has a significant effect on what Hubble's law will look like in the future.